# Properly set redirect 410 (Gone)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

One of my sites has bee hacked. After I cleaned it there are a lot of fake spam URLs in the google. Now I'm trying to set them as 410 Gone and delete them from Google Search Console as well.

What I have tried to add in `.htaccess` but doesn't show `410` instead is showing `404`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



RewriteRule ^https://example.com/156224863/scojgmwtdxy-7/cv.def - [L,NC,G]                                                                                  

</IfModule>
```

If I add this

```
RewriteRule !^index\.html$  https://example.com/156224863/scojgmwtdxy-7/cv.def   [L,R=410]
```

it is redirecting everything. Even root domain `https://example.com/` which I don't want to.

What I miss here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should put something like this in your .htacess file. Please make sure you are clearing your browser cache before testing your URLs. Make sure you escape your HTTP_HOST(domain's name) `.` like `\.` so that regex engine treat it like a literal character.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^156224863/scojgmwtdxy-7/cv\.def/?$ - [R=410,L]
```

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment, everything needs to be redirected to 401
apart from base/root url then one could try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [R=410,L]
```